# Moodle quiz type with regex

Tags: moodle

My academic head of department has given me an interesting question to implement in a Moodle quiz.

I have a quiz question where I present an input edit box. Maybe Cloze, or regular expression type of question type. I'm not sure for now.

The question is worth 2 marks. There is a single input box, and the input is awarded marks based on two subsections of the input string.

Marking scheme1:
**you have followed his advice | without (any) argument**

Meaning of marking scheme1:
If the student typed "you have followed his advice" 1 mark is awarded. If the student's sentence also includes "without argument" or "without any argument" a further 1 mark is awarded. Order of both sections is important. I can't have the student type in "without any argument you have followed his advice" and give 2 marks.

Marking scheme2:
**student should | have to take/do/sit exams**

Meaning of marking scheme2:
If the student typed "student should" 1 mark is awarded. If the student's sentence also includes "have to take exams" or "have to do exams" or "have to sit exams" a further 1 mark is awarded. Order of both sections is important. I can't have the student type in "without any argument you have followed his advice" and give 2 marks.

Any ideas how I can implement this?

regards
Frankie Kam

Postscript.
Rats. Just got downgraded since this is a 'fishing for handouts' kind of question. Thoroughly deserved it. Am now learning about regex via http://regexone.com/ so that in future my questions can be more research-oriented and more constructive....!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, no one helped me out since I was asking without giving evidence of prior research. So instead of relying on a fish handout, I decided to cast my own lure and to catch fish on my own. I mean, Google on my own. Okay, after 48 hours of fishing around the whole entire World Wide Web, I've got the answer!

The trick is to use the "Regular Expression Short Answer question type" syntax inside a Moodle Cloze question type syntax. Confusing? Hopefully the below links and info will make it clearer:

1. You need to download and install the "Regular Expression Short Answer question type" plugin from here https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=qtype_regexp

Download and install to your /question/type/ folder.

```
{2:REGEXP:~=students should have to take exams~=students should have to (take|do|sit) 
exams~%50%students should.*#Feedback for half credit answer~%50%.*(have to 
(take|do|sit) exams)$#Feedback for half credit answer}

{2: ... } means that this question is worth 2 marks

{..:REGEXP:...} identifies this question as a regular expression variant of the short 
answer question type. It accepts non-case sensitive input strings and processes them 
accordingly.

"~=students should have to take exams" (minus the ")
```

means this is a 100% answer worth 2 marks.

2. Make sure you also download and install the required Behaviour more plugins on your moodle installation. Those plugins are 2 question behaviours, located at:
   https://github.com/rezeau/moodle-qbehaviour_regexpadaptivewithhelp
   and
   https://github.com/rezeau/moodle-qbehaviour_regexpadaptivewithhelpnopenalty
   OR download from moodle's plugin repository, at http://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=category&id=31
   Download both and install to your /question/behaviour/ folder.
3. In order for the "Regular Expression Short Answer question type" syntax to be used inside a Cloze syntax (more on this is a short while), you need to copy the 2 hacked files of and overwrite your /question/type/multianswer folder.

You can read about this crucial step on:
http://docs.moodle.org/25/en/question/type/regexp#The_RegExp_Short_Answer_Question

4. Study up on Regular Expressions! No substitute for knowing the basics. I mean, how do expect to win at chess or futsal or bridge, without knowing the rules and fundamentals? So quit yer yapping and get googling to some of the best regex resources on the Net. There are three categories of regex resources that I used to do the job.

4.1 For Regex Newbie:
    http://regexone.com/

4.2 For More references, coding examples and syntax:
    https://kb.wisc.edu/moodle/page.php?id=26623
    http://www.stedee.id.au/Learn_Regular_Expressions-WildCards
    http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/perl/exA.html
    http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/regexhelp.html
    http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

4.3 Interactive Regex Tool for testing Regex code outcomes (very useful!):
    http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

5. Now to get down to the moodle workshop basement to get out hands dirty with some raw coding and all that algorithmy stuff thingies. You know the ones that computer scientists, software engineers and programmers spout that flies over the average IT user's head. I'm taking about regex code, baby! This section is what you users of stackoverflow came here for. See if you have a better solution than mind. Oh, yes, that was a dare.

Take the below code for example.

```
I don't think {2:REGEXP:~=students should have to take exams~=students should have to 
(take|do|sit) exams~%50%students should.*#Feedback for half credit answer~%50%.*(have 
to (take|do|sit) exams)$#Feedback for half credit answer} exams.
```

The resulting screen is this.

[image: A short answer syntax that has been injected with regular expression steroids to beef up its powers. Yeah, baby!]

Let's break it down into alphabet soup, now shall we?

```
"~=students should have to (take|do|sit) exams"
```

means that Noodle, I mean Moodle, will award 2 full awesome marks to any one of these inputs:

```
students should have to take exams
students should have to do exams
students should have to sit exams

"~%50%students should.*"
```

means that Moodle's quiz engine will award 1 mark (that's 50% of 2 marks) if the first half of the input contains the non-case sensitive string "students should". So an input like "students should gobbledegook" will give you 1 mark.

```
"~%50%.*(have to (take|do|sit) exams)$#Feedback for half credit answer"
```

means that you get 1 mark out of 2 marks if you enter a string where the sentence ends with:

"have to take exams" or 
"have to do exams" or
"have to sit exams".

The dollar symbol ($) is the brains behind this regex code that detects if the sentence ends with that particular string value. So, a input of that ends with "Cruise have to do exams, baby!" will not match. Only a sentence like "Cruise climbs Dubai Tower and they still have to do exams" will match indeed.

So there you have it. I've managed to game the regex game. Checkmate my regex nemesis! You've been plaguing me all my programming life. Now it's time the tables were turned on you, you regex bogeyman! I've finally achived a decent level of regex inderstanding, enough for me to write and program a Moodle question type that has some artificial, pesudo-fake Artificial Intelligence in it.

Now that I've answered my own question, it's time to raise the score on this StackOverflow post from a despicable -2 to let's say N positive. Punch in your votes, fellow stackoverflow earthlings!

regards,
Frankie "I'm going only sightly mad with this regex stuff" Kam
Praise The Lord!

Comment: Haha. I am reading this again after more than 2 years. A good refresher for me.

Comment: Hey, are you aware of an update for this hack for Moodle 3.3? Thanks ;)